# How do not allow absolute positioned block to grow outside of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have absolute positioned block which should grow down if its content growth but not go outside of the screen (create scroller on the inner content block).
How to do this?

UPD: `header` block can also has variable height, so I can't use its fixed height. But I don't want it to have scroll.

*(Please, update the title of the question, I'm not sure about it)*

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.article {
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, eligendi amet a dolores laboriosam illo temporibus voluptatibus. Inventore voluptate, tenetur nobis architecto aut, veritatis suscipit itaque corrupti, optio totam sapiente.</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">footer</div>
  <div class="article">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea fugit voluptatibus ipsum molestiae incidunt voluptates in accusamus minus iure amet, voluptatum neque laborum est ducimus eius illo eligendi veritatis voluptas!</div>
    <div>Fugiat dolores blanditiis illo, odio eligendi quam dolor odit asperiores dignissimos reiciendis cupiditate. Maiores, soluta. Possimus error nam ipsum eaque dolor voluptatibus autem, animi quas, sed, eveniet vitae repellat unde!</div>
    <div>Officia nemo quas at facere eum esse cum aliquid quibusdam, magni quasi. Voluptas, ad odit possimus accusantium dolorem fuga voluptatum vero consequuntur ullam itaque laborum aut reprehenderit, facilis, commodi unde.</div>
    <div>Iusto saepe quaerat corporis. Exercitationem ipsum aliquam nisi nemo dolor libero at quam dolorum rerum, praesentium, sequi fugit, eius mollitia provident inventore recusandae. Atque nesciunt suscipit rem tempora harum quos.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quos molestiae soluta laborum amet explicabo magnam. Consectetur quod quae ex commodi vel, aspernatur repellat sunt sequi reiciendis, qui, a temporibus.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `flex-box` could help you here:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px); /* screen height - 10px margin top and bottom */
}

.header {
  background-color: pink;
  flex-grow: 1; 
}

.article {
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1; /* allow to grow as needed */
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, eligendi amet a dolores laboriosam illo temporibus voluptatibus. Inventore voluptate, tenetur nobis architecto aut, veritatis suscipit itaque corrupti, optio totam sapiente.</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">footer</div>
  <div class="article">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea fugit voluptatibus ipsum molestiae incidunt voluptates in accusamus minus iure amet, voluptatum neque laborum est ducimus eius illo eligendi veritatis voluptas!</div>
    <div>Fugiat dolores blanditiis illo, odio eligendi quam dolor odit asperiores dignissimos reiciendis cupiditate. Maiores, soluta. Possimus error nam ipsum eaque dolor voluptatibus autem, animi quas, sed, eveniet vitae repellat unde!</div>
    <div>Officia nemo quas at facere eum esse cum aliquid quibusdam, magni quasi. Voluptas, ad odit possimus accusantium dolorem fuga voluptatum vero consequuntur ullam itaque laborum aut reprehenderit, facilis, commodi unde.</div>
    <div>Iusto saepe quaerat corporis. Exercitationem ipsum aliquam nisi nemo dolor libero at quam dolorum rerum, praesentium, sequi fugit, eius mollitia provident inventore recusandae. Atque nesciunt suscipit rem tempora harum quos.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quos molestiae soluta laborum amet explicabo magnam. Consectetur quod quae ex commodi vel, aspernatur repellat sunt sequi reiciendis, qui, a temporibus.</div>
```

Here is a version with less text to show how it would behave:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

.header {
  background-color: pink;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.article {
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, eligendi amet a dolores laboriosam illo temporibus voluptatibus. Inventore voluptate, tenetur nobis architecto aut, veritatis suscipit itaque corrupti, optio totam sapiente.</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">footer</div>
  <div class="article">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea fugit voluptatibus ipsum molestiae incidunt voluptates in accusamus </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quos molestiae soluta laborum amet explicabo magnam. Consectetur quod quae ex commodi vel, aspernatur repellat sunt sequi reiciendis, qui, a temporibus.</div>
```